# Getting aggregate function column does not exist error in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one class named MstarHoldings and that is an object referring to the table MstarHoldings in the database which has three primary keys investmentId, start_date, and holder_id. I want to use an aggregate function sum and execute a query. I am trying the following code. I did that and I am trying to fetch single query.

```
Long sum = (Long) rdsSession.createNativeQuery(DBQueries.GET_FLOAT_SHARES)
                                .setParameter("investmentId", investmentId, StringType.INSTANCE)
                                .setParameter("startDate", filteredStartDate.get(i), LocalDateType.INSTANCE)
                                .setParameter("endDate", filteredEndDate.get(i), LocalDateType.INSTANCE).addEntity(MstarstarHoldings.class)
        
                                .getSingleResult();
```

The query is as follows.

```
select sum(holdings) holdings "
        + "where morningstar_investment_id = :investmentId and start_date between :startDate and :endDate
```

I cannot include holder_id which is the primary key because I want only one result from this query and if I include holder_id, it gives me two records. Now I am getting the following error.

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "holdings" does not exist
Position: 12

Is there any particular way and get one value without getting this error

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `.addEntity(MstarstarHoldings.class)` is not what you want to have here. Also note that your query returns 4 values (sum(holdings), mstar_investment_id, start_date and is_deleted) but that cast to `Long` indicates you only want one.

Comment: Then what we can have there? Any workaround you can suggest?

Comment: Didn't use that in a while but how about  just `createNativeQuery("the query", Long.class)` and just not using `addEntity()`? Alternatively have a look at `addScalar()` for which you might have to provide an alias to `sum(holdings)`.

Comment: Just tried some updates in the code. Can you check the updated question?

Comment: It seems you only updated the query and I'm also not sure using `holdings` as the alias for `sum(holdings)` would work (try to "unroll" it: holdings = sum(holdings)? or sum(sum(sum(sum(holdings)))) etc.?).

Comment: Used add scalar both with and withour MstarHoldings.addentity. Getting column does not exist error.

Comment: Well, does that column exist? Is the name spelled correctly?

Comment: That is an alias column name. select sum(holdings) holdings

Comment: Check my comments above. You can't use the alias inside `sum()` as well as to gie a name to the sum itself. Also, at some point you need to use the real column name or the DB doesn't know what the alias is refering to.